# Create a input field to enter MMYY for credit card expiry date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I am have a form input field for a customers credit card expiry date.

I am currently using a textbox for this but was wondering if bootstrap has something that could limit the user to entering 4 digits only?  MM/YYYY

e.g.

```
05/2015
```

Comment: It would be nice for your users if you'd also handle a slash or a dash between the month and the year.

Comment: @cvrebert yes that would be great also

Answer (score 2):

In HTML you can limit the max length of a field using `maxlength="6"` attribute.

In your example something like:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="6" placeholder="MMYYYY">
```

But for something more complex you need to use some javascript function.
Like:

```
function checkExpiry() {
  var s = $('#inputExp').val();

  if (/^\d{6}$/.test(s)) {
   return true;
  } else {
    // show error
    return false;
  }
}
```

starting from this you can improve the tests.. like checking the month and the year (superficially, the real checks must be done server-side)

```
/^[01][0-9]20[12][0-9]$/
```